# Why is there unnecessary gap on top my div?

Tags: css, html

I want to achieve this:
[image]

But there is unnecessary gap on top of the Social icons div. The page is live at http://goo.gl/K17Fjs

My markup:-

```
<header>
<img src="images/home-layout_02.jpg" alt="Salem Al Hajri Logo">
<div id="top-social">
Follow us on <img src="images/home-layout_05_01.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/home-layout_05_02.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/home-layout_05_03.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Services</li>
<li>Projects</li>
<li>Photo Gallery</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
/*background-image: url(images/home-layout_08.jpg);*/
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom;
}
header {width: 920px; margin: 0 auto;}
#top-social {float: right; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 13px; width: 538px;}
nav {float: right; width: 538px; text-align: right; margin-top: 45px;}
nav li { display: inline;}
```

Comment: Try float:left on your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your layout, you need to float your logo image left.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/y7re9/)**

*Add this CSS :*

```
header > img {
    float: left;
}
```

This : `header > img {}` means propeties will apply only to the first children images of the `<header>` tag in your case, the logo image and not to the social icons.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "padding-top: 13px;" from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your style.css line:10 to:

```
#top-social {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*padding-top: 13px;*/
  width: 538px;
}
```

There is a top padding of 13 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `float: right` will be pushed down by other elements that come before them.  You can fix this by changing your markup to move the `#top-social` and `nav` *before* the `<img>`.

However, in this case I think it would be better to absolutely position the top social and the nav to the top right and bottom right of the containing header.  This will allow you to easily get the nav links below the social links and keep this appearance.

```
header {
    position: relative;
}
#top-social {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```